# better_errors requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

Bundle fails to install better_errors.

```
Gem::InstallError: better_errors requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0.
An error occurred while installing better_errors (2.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install better_errors -v '2.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

But `gem install better_errors` works fine.

`ruby --version` says `ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux-gnu]`. I already tried upgrading to 2.1 but still not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: are you using a version-manager for several rubies (if so, which one)? is there a ruby-version stated in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem. In my case, the bundler script had

```
 #!/usr/bin/ruby
```

as the initial line in the script. As a result, it was calling the system (non-rbenv) version, which was 1.9.1 (in Linux Mint)

It's pretty hacky but changing that first line by running

sudo nano /usr/local/bin/bundle

to the full path for the rbenv shim (in my case):

```
 #!/home/$YOUR_USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi for all the people who have different versions of ruby in their machine, and even if

`rvm use ruby-version` doesn't work.

Try this,

`rvm list` this will specify all the ruby version in your machine.

```
rvm rubies

 * ruby-1.9.3-p484 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.0-preview2 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.1 [ x86_64 ]
=> ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
```

In your project root folder, just create a file

.ruby-version

and add the ruby version you are planning to use.

```
ruby-2.1.5
```

Thats it, restart your application and try reinstalling your gems. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use rvm, make sure you don't have an `.rvmrc` file at the root of your project that force ruby < 2.0 to run, same with rbenv and `.ruby-version` file